# Shorthand for grabbing files in a subdirectory in Matlab

Tags: matlab, path

I have a data folder in /home/me/project/data that contains image files. In project is my script. I wish to imread all the images in this file. When I do the following `dirData = dir('.\data\*.jpg');` `I get Error using imread (line 349)`. Is there a way to refer to this directory without having to specify the full path?

Comment: You have to use a `for` loop or some other iteration method like `arrayfun`

Comment: I found a short way of doing this: currentFolder = pwd; dir(fullfile(strcat(currentFolder,'/data/*.jpg'))). I wonder if there is a better to do it

Comment: `dir('./data/*.jpg')` works for me. Or `dir('data/*.jpg')`